# DrawingVisual is not refreshed

Tags: wpf, rendering

I create my own `FrameworkElement` and override `VisualChildrenCount{get;}` and `GetVisualChild(int index)` by returning my own `DrawingVisual` instance.

If I modify the content of the visual after initial rendering (e.g. in timer handler) using `DrawingVisual.RenderOpen()` and drawing into the context, the element is not refreshed.

Here's the simplest sample:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace VisualTest
{
    public class TestControl : FrameworkElement
    {
        private readonly DrawingVisual _visual = new DrawingVisual();

        public TestControl()
        {
            Draw(false);

            var timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)};
            timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
                              {
                                  Draw(true);
                                  InvalidateVisual();
                                  timer.Stop();
                              };
            timer.Start();
        }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            return _visual;
        }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }

        private void Draw(bool second)
        {
            DrawingContext ctx = _visual.RenderOpen();
            if (!second)
                ctx.DrawRoundedRectangle(Brushes.Green, null, new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200), 20, 20);
            else
                ctx.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Red, null, new Point(100, 100), 100, 100);
            ctx.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

`InvalidateVisual()` does nothing. Although if you resize the window containing the element, it gets updated.

Any ideas on how to properly refresh the content? Preferably **without** introducing new dependency properties for my element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add

```
this.AddVisualChild(_visual);
this.AddLogicalChild(_visual);
```

to TestControl class constructor.

Comment: This code will cause the visual to leak memory, as it is added to the tree, but never removed. A better code is to add the visual on Loaded event, and remove it on Unloaded event - see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Based on [SMART_n's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663178/46635), here is an improved solution that doesn't leak memory:

```
    public TestControl()
    {
        Loaded += AddVisualToTree;
        Unloaded += RemoveVisualFromTree;

        Draw(false);

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)};
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
                          {
                              Draw(true);
                              InvalidateVisual();
                              timer.Stop();
                          };
        timer.Start();

    }

    private void AddVisualToTree(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddVisualChild(_visual);
        AddLogicalChild(_visual);
    }

    private void RemoveVisualFromTree(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveLogicalChild(_visual);
        RemoveVisualChild(_visual);
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Note that Loaded and Unloaded can occur multiple times throughout the framework element's lifetime -- I assumed they were invoked just once which lead to my visual not repainting after a few hours of idling.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `_visual` a `DrawingGroup`, you can re-open it later and change it's drawing commands, and they will be updated.